# $http.post to MVC controller has a property / parameter confilct

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Can someone please educate me on why I cannot have a JSON property with the same name as an MVC controller parameter? I'm sure I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere, but here is the scenario:

I commit an $http.post to an MVC controller

$http.post method:

```
return $http.post("/Api/Form/Create/Save/DraftForm/", {"Model":"test"});
```

MVC Model

```
public class FormViewModel
{ 
    public string Model { get; set; } 
}
```

MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost, Route("Api/Form/Create/Save/DraftForm")
public ActionResult Create_Save_DraftForm(FormViewModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

By the time someObj gets to the controller, it is null.

However, if I change the name of the parameter in the controller "model" to something like "viewModel", it works fine.

```
[HttpPost, Route("Api/Form/Create/Save/DraftForm")
public ActionResult Create_Save_DraftForm(FormViewModel viewModel)
{
    ....
}
```

As Shyju mentioned, I can also rename the "model" property in the JSON object to another name and it works as well:

```
public class FormViewModel
{ 
    public string AnotherModel { get; set; } 
}

return $http.post("/Api/Form/Create/Save/DraftForm/", {"AnotherModel":"test"});
```

Comment: Could be a bug in the Model binder ! Rename your property to a specific name and it will work (Ex  : CarModel)

Comment: So far that has been my solution. It's either a bug in the Model binder, or I am using the Model binder improperly. If I had to guess, I would say it is the latter.

Comment: It has been mentioned to me that I might want to try adding another level to the object, but I didn't have any luck with that.

Comment: Correction, adding another level did the trick. I will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood how data was getting posted to the controller.

The controller is getting

```
{"Model", "test"},
```

but is expecting

```
{ "model":
    {"Model", "test"}
}
```

Basically, the data being passed to the controller should have a property name that matches the controller parameter, and the property should be an object that matches the parameter's object in the controller.